# Trying to read data into memory

Tags: arrays, vba, split

I am trying to read the following data into memory to pass this into Excel cells. However, it seems to only read as one 'line'.

```
Component details Export from File:-
="Reference","Description","Number","Custom"
="Hello",="Test data",="J125",="Door"
="Hello",="Test data",="J126",="Door"
="Hello",="Test data",="J127",="Door"
="Hello",="Test data",="J128",="Door"
="Hello",="Test data",="J129",="Door"
="Hello",="Test data",="J130",="Door"
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
strfile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "CATIA Data")

If strfile = False Then
    GoTo HERE:
End If
Open strfile For Input As #1
    
        ROW_NUMBER = 1
        Do Until EOF(1)

           Line Input #1, linefromfile
           counter = 1

           Result = Split(linefromfile, ",")
           For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())
               DisplayText = DisplayText & Result(i) & vbNewLine
               counter = counter + 1
                   
               J = i + 1
               ws.Cells(ROW_NUMBER, J) = Replace(Result(i), Chr(34), "")
           Next i
        
           ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER + 1                        
        Loop
Close
```

Unfortunately for the compare and update I want to do with this macro, the import CSV would work very well, I think it would be cleaner to import into memory then pick the bits of data I want to put into the worksheet.

Comment: Consider renaming `i` and `J` to `SrcColumnIndex` and `DstColumnIndex` (and then `ROW_NUMBER` can be `DstRowIndex` and `counter` can be `SrcLineIndex`; the `SCREAM_CASE` doesn't seem warranted here). What is `DisplayText` and where is it used? It's being written to, but not read. Assuming the output goes to `ws.Cells(...)`, then `ws.Cells(DstRowIndex, DstColumnIndex).Formula = Replace(Result(SrcColumnIndex), Chr(34), vbNullString)` reads exactly right. Have you tried hitting F9 inside the loop to set a breakpoint, then F8 to step through and inspect locals? Is everything as expected?

Comment: Are you wanting to strip out the `=` in front of each value?  If you write that value (with the `=`), Excel will interpret `="Hello"` as a formula -- which shows as an error.

Comment: Please, try explaining (in words) what you want accomplishing. Reading our question text and looking to the code, I am not sure I understand... Do you want replacing of double quotes? Why do you not simple open the csv file in Excel?

Comment: Opening the file in Excel would be more robust.  For example what happens with your code if one or more field values contain commas?   Excel knows how to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple immediate issues that will cause an error.

1. Your `Ubound` and `LBound` coding is wrong. Get rid of the parenthesis.
2. You need more quotes to insert into excel as a formula like `="Hello"` or you need to substitute out the formula and quotes (it's not clear what your objective is).
3. If you want to use the literal formula on some columns, but not others, you'll need to create an if statement for the column.

I ran the modified code below against your test text file and got the below result. You can see/test if you [get your own copy of file here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4I4R3tigH-imp6bvA?e=xisp0m).

[image]

```
Sub fixCSVLOAD()

strfile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "CATIA Data")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Open strfile For Input As #1
    
        ROW_NUMBER = 1
        Do Until EOF(1)

           Line Input #1, linefromfile
           counter = 1

           Result = Split(linefromfile, ",")
           For i = LBound(Result) To UBound(Result)
               DisplayText = DisplayText & Result(i) & vbNewLine
               counter = counter + 1
                   
               j = i + 1
               If i = 2 Then
                ws.Cells(ROW_NUMBER, j) = Replace(Result(i), Chr(34), "")
                Else
                
                ws.Cells(ROW_NUMBER, j) = Replace(Result(i), Chr(34), """")
                
                End If
                
           Next i
        
           ROW_NUMBER = ROW_NUMBER + 1
        Loop
Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou!! I tried that but it didn't split the code and put in on separate rows in Excel.., It just continued on row one?? It's like it is not recognising vbNewline

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with your CSV file. As I said, the code works as shown in that shared file so I'd be most appreciative if you clicked the green check to accept my answer. You can see the CSV I used by clicking here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g4I3pO7SrI9KCbKlkg?e=tEHW8a

Good luck.